# What is the return value of kill when sig 0 is sent to process where TARGET REAL UID == CURRENT EFFECTIVE UID?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a case where kill will return something other than 0 when signal 0 is sent to another process?  Specifically curious about the case where the sending process has CURRENT UID equal to the target process REAL UID.

Does this permission set mean that the sending process does have permission to signal the target process?

Comment: Note, from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html : `If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but existence and permission
       checks are still performed; this can be used to check for the
       existence of a process ID or process group ID that the caller is
       permitted to signal.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. The only errors described by [the Open Group specification for `kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) are:

- `EINVAL` if the signal number is invalid (not applicable here)
- `EPERM` if the process does not have permissions to send the signal
- `ESRCH` if the target process does not exist

So long as the target process exists and can be signalled by your process, calling `kill()` with a signal number of 0 will return success.